# Android, menu showAsAction="always" being ignored

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

There are lots of questions regard my problem but I believe I'm following those answers but still when I launch the application my item is not visible (it's under over flow menu).

This my menu.xml

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_sort_asc"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_sort"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"/>

...
```

`MainActivity` extended `Activity` and not `ActionBarActivity`. Although Android studio preview shows it in Actionbar (and other items inside overflow), however, this item is not visible when I launch the app.

Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: try to `Extends FragmentActivity`

Comment: @M D, Nop, is still under overflow menu :(

Comment: Just remove `app:showAsAction` and try   `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` . It's perfect working in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced this problem once , try adding  android:showAsAction="always" too

Comment: that's working fine but have no idea why Editor display error and ask to use `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`.

Comment: i don't know what causes this behaviour but if it makes you feel better try adding tools:ignore="AppCompatResource"

Comment: that would ignore that line. basically when you're using app:showAsAction , you're using the support's library definition and when you're using the android:showAsAction you're using the current sdk one, which may be not supported by older versions that's why your IDE is complaining...